# PropertyAccessException in Postgresql Server

Tags: java, spring

I am beginner of Spring, I have created simple spring web app using postgresql. I used jdbcTemplate in spring.

Following is my error log

> INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@3d99d22e: startup date [Sat May 19 15:46:09 PDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
>   May 19, 2018 3:46:10 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>   INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
>   May 19, 2018 3:46:11 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
>   INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: org.postgresql.Driver
>   May 19, 2018 3:46:11 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
>   WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentJDBCTemplate' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
>   PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
>   Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentJDBCTemplate' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
>   PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1646)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
>       at com.eql.main.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:18)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
>   PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:122)
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
>       ... 13 more
>   And below is Beans.xml

```html
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

   <!-- Initialization for data source -->
   <bean id="dataSource" 
      class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name = "driverClassName" value = "org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb"/>
      <property name = "username" value = "postgres"/>
      <property name = "password" value = "sql123"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- Definition for studentJDBCTemplate bean -->
   <bean id = "studentJDBCTemplate" 
      class = "com.eql.jdbctemplate.StudentJDBCTemplate">
      <property name = "dataSource" ref = "dataSource" />    
   </bean>
      
</beans>
```

and Class is StudentJDBCTemplate.class

```
public class StudentJDBCTemplate implements StudentDAO{
   private DataSource dataSource;
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;


   public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
       this.dataSource = dataSource;
       this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
   }
   public void create(String name, Integer age) {
         String SQL = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";
          jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL, name, age);
          System.out.println("Created Record Name = " + name + " Age = " + age);
          return;
   }
   public Student getStudent(Integer id) {
       String SQL = "select * from Student where id = ?";
          Student student = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, 
          new Object[]{id}, new StudentMapper());

          return student;
   }
   public List<Student> listStudents(){
       String SQL = "select * from Student";
          List <Student> students = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new StudentMapper());
          return students;
   }
   public void delete(Integer id) {
       String SQL = "delete from Student where id = ?";
          jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, id);
          System.out.println("Deleted Record with ID = " + id );
          return;
   }
   public void update(Integer id, Integer age) {
       String SQL = "update Student set age = ? where id = ?";
          jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, age, id);
          System.out.println("Updated Record with ID = " + id );
          return;
   }
```

}

Can anybody try to give solution for the same

In advance thanks...

Comment: `public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {` should be `public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {`

Comment: Its working...Thank you Sascha Frinken